# Implementing a random process on binary tree

Tags: algorithm, random, tree, binary-tree, implementation

consider this random process on a complete binary tree with N = 2^h - 1 nodes

Suppose that I have a binary tree with N=2^h−1 nodes, initially all nodes are unmarked Over time via this process nodes became marked. Suppose that nodes have unique identifiers in range of [1,N] each time, I send you the identifier of a node. when you receive a sent node. you mark it and also invoke the following marking rule, which takes effect before I send out next node.

If a node and its sibling are marked, its parent is marked.
If a node and its parent are marked, the other sibling is marked.
The marking rule is applied recursively as much as possible before the next node is sent.

I need to implement this process and run it ten times for h in range [10, 20] and find out how many times I should send a node to completely mark all of the nodes ...

**My question is**: *What is the best way to represent binary tree for this problem?* 
What comes to my mind is to treat it like a heap and use an array of `int nodes[1 << h]` and do the *marking rule*, Or I use a pointer based structure like BST ?

Another thing that I have difficulty to understand is that, *How should I implement the marking rule described above?*(also you should note that this rule must be applied as much as possible) I mean in terms of a function taking a node as a parameter and ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a Heap and initialize all it's elements to 0. Marking can be done by setting the keys to 1. Then you can use the following procedures:

```
MARK(A, i)
l = LEFT(i)
r = RIGHT(i)
p = PARENT(i)
if(i <= A.heap-size and A[i] == 0)
    A[i] = 1
    if(l <= A.heap-size and r <= A.heap-size)
        if(A[l] == 1)
            if(A[r] == 0)
                MARK(A, r)
        else if(A[r] == 1)
            MARK(A, l)
    if(p != NIL)
        CHECK(A, p)

CHECK(A, i)
l = LEFT(i)
r = RIGHT(i)
if(l <= A.heap-size and A[l] == 1 and r <= A.heap-size and A[r] == 1)
    MARK(A, i)
```